# How can I get my numbers to stop acting as a string in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a code that pretty much does what I need it to do, which is compare values on different spreadsheets and, if they're have the same info, add up their values, but I noticed the numbers are behaving as strings, which means, 4+1 is giving me 41 not 5. Is it because of the way I wrote the code or is there any way to fix it? The rest of the code is pretty much just me calling columns on the spreadsheet, important part is:

```
for (let i =0; i<tamanho; i++){
    for (let c=0; c<tamanhodenomes; c++) {
      if (vendidos[i][0] == nomes[c][0]){
        totalvendido[c][0]+=quantidadevendida[i][0]
        console.log(totalvendido)
    }
```

Comment: Wrap them with Number();

Comment: Make sure the column is of type number, here's what I mean https://i.gyazo.com/0642db1ad0174a95c82f30639244208a.mp4

Answer (score 2):

```
for (let i =0; i<tamanho; i++){
    for (let c=0; c<tamanhodenomes; c++) {
      if (vendidos[i][0] == nomes[c][0]){
        totalvendido[c][0]+=Number(quantidadevendida[i][0]);
        console.log(totalvendido)
    }
```

Comment: This made sense, but somehow, didn't change the outcome.

Comment: perhaps you need `totalvendido[c][0]=Number(totalvendido[c][0]) + Number(quantidadevendida[i][0]);` if `totalvendido[c][0]` is a string - note (or)`totalvendido[c][0]= +totalvendido[c][0] + +quantidadevendida[i][0];`

Comment: @JaromandaX seems we were writing at the same time...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I've used parseInt() in this situation, so:

```js
for (let i =0; i<tamanho; i++){
    for (let c=0; c<tamanhodenomes; c++) {
      if (vendidos[i][0] == nomes[c][0]){
        totalvendido[c][0] = parseInt(totalvendido[c][0]) + parseInt(quantidadevendida[i][0])
        console.log(totalvendido)
    }
```